# Object outline appears when using ID Mask

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, render-layers, masking, id-mask

I have an ID Mask, and this yellow-like line appears in my render when I'm using the ID Mask node. (The line appears around the drawers on the right side os the image)

[image]

[image]

I tried using the Fast Gausian Blur node on the Mask Image to get rid of it, but the image was blurred and the line was still sharp. What's causing this line to appear and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Did you blur mask or footage?  You can try to dilate/errode mask at first and then blur it, if you want smooth transition

Comment: Blurred the footage going into the Mix Shader of the ID Mask.

Comment: Sharpness and value of Mask controls how images will mix with each other.